# mysql join tables, query returns only rows with matching rows

Tags: mysql, join

Currently I have this mysql :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT blog.id, blog_comments.cid, blog.name,
  blog.blogtext, blog.date, blog.like, blog.dislike, blog_comments.comment, blog_comments.date
FROM blog, blog_comments  
WHERE blog.id = blog_comments.cid   
ORDER BY blog.id DESC LIMIT 30")
```

The query returns rows and their comments, the problem is: it ONLY returns rows with their comments, it doesn't return rows WITHOUT comments. I've found a few topics, and discovered that I probably should use `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Now I've tried to apply this, absence success.

Assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than an implicit join (comma-separated list of tables produces an [`INNER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join)), use an explicit [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join):

```
SELECT 
  blog.id,
  blog_comments.cid,
  blog.name,
  blog.blogtext,
  blog.date, 
  blog.like, 
  blog.dislike, 
  blog_comments.comment, 
  blog_comments.date
FROM 
 blog
 /* LEFT JOIN will return rows from blog (the "left" side of the join) even if no 
    related rows exist in blog_comments (the "right" side of the join) */
 LEFT JOIN blog_comments ON blog.id = blog_comments.cid   
ORDER BY blog.id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer :) got it working like charm now, good night!